# Appending MS Word DOC files with Perl programming

Tags: perl, ms-word

I have an issue with MS Word. I have two MS Word DOC files (contains logos, tables, text). I want to append one end of another in the same file format with a Perl script. I googled lots of sites but failed. Do you have any idea on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you can try to solve your task with the `Win32::Clipboard` Perl module. That is the good start point. Additional information you can find here: http://www.perl.com/pub/2005/05/26/word_control.html.

Another module that can be useful for you is `Win32::OLE`. Small example of usage: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/perl/word.html

Comment: @Mahesh sorry you don't have the [needed reputation yet to upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up).